# Centering Image with centre align clashing with Position In CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I am new to html and css and recently I started making a canvas game. I wish to have an image and align it in the centre of the canvas with HTML. I used the 'position: Absolute' property and could at least put it on the canvas but when I used the 'text-align: centre' property, my position property stopped working and came below the canvas.

So I wanted to know, how I can centre my image on the canvas.

CSS

```
#startgameimg{
    text-align:center;
    width: 50px;
    display:block;
    margin:auto;    
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>GAME</title>

    <link href = "style.css" rel = "stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    
    <div style = "text-align: center;">    
        <canvas 
            id = "canvas" 
            height = "560"
            width = "800"
            style = "border:5px solid rgb(33, 8, 61)"
            >Your Browser is Not Supported</canvas>

            <div id = 'start'>
                <img src = "play.png" alt = "" id = "startgameimg"/>
            </div>
    </div>
    <script src = "script.js" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please Note: I went through about 5 to 6 Stack Overflow questions regarding the same topic but couldn't find any solution

Comment: display: flex;  justify-content: center;  align-items: center; Use this and check

Answer (score 0):

```css
#startgameimg{
    text-align:center;
    width: auto;
    display:block;
    margin:auto;    
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%, -50%)
    
}
```

```html
 <div style = "text-align: center; position: reletive">    
        <canvas 
            id = "canvas" 
            height = "560"
            width = "800"
            style = "border:5px solid rgb(33, 8, 61)"
            >Your Browser is Not Supported</canvas>

            <div id = 'start'>
                <img src = "play.png" alt = "MY IMG" id = "startgameimg"/>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).